# Append file data in another file

Tags: android, file, android-file

In my present scenario, i created a file of lat/longs, and upload that file on server after every 3 minutes. when i got a response for successful uploaded from server , i delete that file. i want to move that file data into another file before deletion as for backup. i used the following:

```
  private void moveFile(String inputPath, String inputFile, String outputPath) {

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {

            //create output directory if it doesn't exist
            File dir = new File (outputPath);
            if (!dir.exists())
            {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }


            in = new FileInputStream(inputPath + inputFile);
            out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + inputFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            in.close();
            in = null;

            // write the output file
          out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;

            // delete the original file
           // new File(inputPath + inputFile).delete();


        }
```

but this move the old data from backup file and write new data instead of it. i want to add new data into existing file without deletion of old data. i am stuck on it from last 2 days. please help me guys

Answer (score 0):

Look over this class and constructor which second argument is true it means that will append file .

```
public class LatLongFileWriter {

private File file;
FileWriter writer;

public LatLongFileWriter (File file) {
    this.file = file;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void writeLatLong(String data) {
    try {
        writer.append(data);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

You can write like

```
    LatLongFileWriter mFileWriter = new LatLongFileWriter (csvFile1);
    mFileWriter.writeLatLong("DATA");
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using FileOutputStream, the constructor take in two parameters, first param is either a file or a file path that point to the file and the second param is whether to append or not.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(yourFile, true);
fos.write(yourString.getBytes());
fos.close();
```